# Part of speech of 'to' in the following Context:

Tags: grammar, prepositions, ambiguity, parts-of-speech

As explained in the [article](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/rules-for-prepositions.html) , verbs that follow prepositions are usually gerund forms that act as nouns instead of verbs(usually Verb+ing). But in the sentence: "Tell John to bring some food", 'bring' is clearly a verb and not a noun. So, which part of speech is 'to' in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "to" is used to accompany the infinitive form of a verb, it is known as the "**infinitive particle**" or "**infinitive marker**" (or in the documentation of some part-of-speech tagging software, simply "infinitive to").

So, for example, take the following sentence:

> I went to the store to buy some food.

The first "to" is a preposition. The second is an infinitive particle that accompanies the infinitive verb "*buy*".